# synthetic currency pair

Tags: fx, synthetic

I want to generate price of a synthetic currency pair. For example, I have EURGBP, GBPUSD prices and I want to generate EURUSD price. I preferred to use these already existing currency pairs to verify the calculation.

EURUSD(ask) = EURGBP(ask) * GBPUSD(ask)

EURUSD(bid) = EURGBP(bid) * GBPUSD(bid)

Is this correct?

Thanks in advence

Comment: Yes that looks right. You can see these equations in this post: https://sites.google.com/site/marketformula/articles/triangular-arbitrage-101/triangular-arbitrage-bid-ask-quotes under "Example 1: EURUSD synthetic bid and ask"

Answer (score 1):

You can see how to calculate cross currency rates at [FX and MM training](http://www.webstersystems.co.uk/fxmm.htm#spot%20fx)

*disclaimer I authored the page*

Comment: Very nice explanations on that page there Rupert.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's correct:

> **Formula 5.2**
>
> (FCa / FCb)ask = (FCa / DC)ask ×(DC/FCb)ask
>
> (FCa / FCb)bid = (FCa / DC)bid ×(DC/FCb)bid
>
> Where FCa and FCb are the two foreign currencies and DC is the domestic currency.

source: https://www.investopedia.com/exam-guide/cfa-level-1/global-economic-analysis/spot-market.asp